# Change class to links and only allow one to be either active or inactive

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I have a `<ul>` containing three links that, when clicked, loads a corresponding partial into the `<div>` below. I'd like to use some JavaScript/jQuery to detect which partial is loaded. That way I can alter the class of the `<a href>` to `active` or `inactive` for styling purposes.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><%= link_to "Reviews", profile_reviews_profile_path, :class => 'active', :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About", profile_about_profile_path, :class => 'inactive', :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Credits", profile_credits_profile_path, :class => 'inactive', :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <%= render :partial 'profile_reviews %> #default
  </div>
</div><!-- end tabs -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** I used this code and it works, however if I click on the first link it no longer shoes I can't toggle from inactive to active. The other two work great.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.inactive").click(function() {
        $(".active").not(this).toggleClass("inactive active");
        $(this).toggleClass("inactive active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an additional click event in your JS. It would need to run when this page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tabs > ul a").click(function(){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.siblings(".active").toggleClass("active")
    $this.addClass("active"
  })

});
```

This would also work for any other `#tabs` with the same structure in your app. From memory, I don't believe this will affect the `:remote => true` functionality in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I goot the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939341/change-class-of-links-with-default-values-with-jquery):

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar=$('#sidebar');
    sidebar.delegate('a', 'click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```