# Change class of links with default values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three links on which I manually set classes: One defaults to `.active` and the others default to `.inactive`. I have some jQuery that I'm using to toggle the class of the links when they are clicked for CSS purposes. This works for the `.inactive` links - they switch to `.active`. However it doesn't work for the default `.active` link. If I click on the default `.active` link it stays inactive.

Default load:

Link 1 - Active
Link 2 - Inactive
Link 3 - Inactive

Clicking Link 2:

Link 1 - Inactive
Link 2 - Active
Link 3 - Inactive

Clicking Link 1 from Link 2:

Link 1 - Inactive
Link 2 - Active
Link 3 - Inactive

How can I complete this cycle so it works?

**Here is the HTML I'm generating:**

```
<ul id="infoContainer">
  <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_cred" class="active" data-remote="true">Cred</a></li>
  <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_about" class="inactive" data-remote="true">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_questions" class="inactive" data-remote="true">Questions</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The jQuery I'm using:**

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar=$('#sidebar');
    sidebar.delegate('a.inactive', 'click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying the default active stays *in*active?

Comment: It seems like it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/WuqNG/. Clicking link 2 and then 1 again switches classes correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do get you correct, your selector is too strict: handling only the `inactive` links.
Tried the following?

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar=$('#sidebar');
    sidebar.delegate('a', 'click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```